# Swift how to extend my own class in separate files

Tags: swift, categories

I want to do the following:

MyClass.swift:

```
public class MyClass {
    ...
}
```

MyClass+Extension.swift:

```
extension MyClass {
   ...
}
```

If I have both in the same file it works fine, if they are in separate files I get the following error:

```
"Use of undeclared type 'MyClass'"
```

I already checked the target membership of both files. They are part of the same target.

Comment: You shouldn't do anything special... I do that all the times, with no problem as long as they are in the same module. No idea about why it doesn't work for you

Comment: You were right. Must have been the project settings.

Comment: thank you for that : "I already checked the target membership of both files."

Answer (score 14):

The following will enable you to access your additional functions in MyClass+Extension.swift from anywhere that your original MyClass is accessible, which included outside its module since it had a `public` access level:

```
public extension MyClass {
   ...
}
```